# Curl text to API endpoint

Tags: json, bash, shell, curl

I'm trying make a curl request with the data from the variable. It seems I keep gettin this error when trying to execute. Works fine with variable has no spaces.

> ```
> MACMODEL='MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)'
>   curl  --request POST \
>         --header 'Authorization2: 'token'' \
>         --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
>         --data '{ "model":"'$MACMODEL'" }' \
>          https://endpoint ; echo
> ```

I get the following error

> ```
> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Pro
> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: (Retina,
> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 13-inch,
> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Early
> curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 8
> <html>
>  <head>
>   <title>400 Bad Request</title>
>  </head>
>  <body>
>   <h1>400 Bad Request</h1>
>   The server could not comply with the request since it is either malformed or otherwise incorrect.<br/><br/>
> request contains invalid json body.
> ```

Anyone know how to fix this issue?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem with quotes. In the end, $MACMODEL is no quoted so spaces create the errors. Try this

```
MACMODEL='MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)'
  curl  --request POST \
        --header 'Authorization2: 'token'' \
        --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
        --data '{ "model":"'"$MACMODEL"'" }' \
         https://endpoint ; echo
```

The conflicting line could be broken as

```
--data '{ "model":"'
"$MACMODEL"
'" }' \
```